# Hive Dynamic partition issue

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have 2 tables as below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP_tab(id int,mytime STRING,age int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'hdfs://xxx';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main_TAB(id int,age int)
PARTITIONED BY (mytime STRING)
STORED AS ORC
tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");

FROM TEMP_TAB INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE main_TAB 
PARTITION (mytime) 
SELECT *,substr(mytime,0,10) as mytime;
```

but the strange thing is Insert does not work. It has following error message

> Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot insert into table `m16`.`main_TAB` because the number of columns are different: need 2 columns, but query has 3 columns.; (state=,code=0)

I have already set these 2 as well

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict
```

Comment: @cricket_007, Yes it was a typo. Any advice on this?.

Comment: As the error says, `SELECT *,substr(mytime,0,10) as mytime;` Is producing more columns than are contained in your table. It's trying to insert `(id,mytime,age,mytime)` into a table with columns `(id, age, mytime)`... Not really clear where `DW_CR` is from

Comment: To me, it looks like you have a needless `substr(mytime,0,10) as mytime;`  and you should be following this example.  https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.3/bk_data-access/content/moving_data_from_hdfs_to_hive_external_table_method.html

Comment: There was a typo there as well, corrected. But as per Hive's definition it should accept second select query as partition right?.

Comment: You've selected `mytime` twice. Don't use `*`. But the partition column needs to be inserted last, yes.

Comment: Thanks . You were correct. Instead of *, I had to type all column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that all the typos are fixed, it's easier to see what you're doing.

That last line, you've selected `mytime` twice. I'm not sure why the error doesn't think you have 4 columns, but anyway, don't use the `*` since you have a partition column of the same name as the column in the source table.

```
SELECT id, age, substr(mytime,0,10) as mytime;
```

And when inserting into partitioned tables, I've noticed that the partition column(s) always need to be selected last